# How to map CSS and Javascript resources in `web.xml`?

Tags: xml, jsp, servlets

I'm building a website in MVC architecture ,

Which means that I have to send all `views` requests to the `Controller`.

First all all, this is how my project looks like:

[image]

Using `web.xml`, I'm mapping requests to the controller:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>firstXDw</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>implementations.Controller</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/views/login.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/views/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!--
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/views/login.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/views/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>implementations.Controller</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>admincp</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/views/admincp.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>  

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>handleList</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/views/handleList.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>/views/login.jsp</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/views/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>yourcoupons</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/views/yourcoupons.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/views/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>admincp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/views/admincp.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>handleList</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/views/handleList.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/views/login.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/views/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>yourcoupons</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/views/yourcoupons</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
-->

</web-app>
```

Unfortunately , this is mapping **every request** to the controller, and not only the .JSP files (`views`),

Which makes the resources - `Css` and `Javascript` files unaccessable. (because instread of read them, the controller is called)

How can I map ONLY `.JSP` files?

Something like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/views/*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Thanks in advance! Im using hibernate.

Comment: Why do you store the CSS and the JS files under views in the first place? And what's the point of the mapping of /views/`to Controller? You should never have any direct link to a view anyway.

Comment: @JBNizet Why not? So how should it be , instead?

Comment: Use another folder ( Not views OR sub folder of views) to store CSS/JS/Images

Comment: @Loc   request.getRequestDispatcher(dispatchTo).forward(request, response);

dispatchTo - should be the path to dispatch to , or the servlet name (from web.xml)?

Comment: dispatchTo can be any path that start with /views/. Ex: /view/abc/def.jsp

Comment: @Loc Can't get why MVC is nassecary , everything worked great only with JSP , but thank you anyway. I got your point